# How to pass string between tableview and viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

First, In **todolistviewController**. I have textfield for fill string and buttonSave for save string to show in **tableview1**. this simple note for me.

Next, I create button put on textfield that when tap on textfield will show **tableview2** for pick menu1(String), menu2(String), menu3(String).

When menu picked will back to **todolistviewController** and show menu picked in textfield.  I need to know that how to pass menu(String) to show in textfield.

Answer (score 0):

There are usually two ways to achieve your goal which is to pass an NSString from TabelView2Controller back to TodoListViewController.

First of all, you need to declare an NSString property in TabelView2Controller `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedMune` and update it to your selected menu(String) in the UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Then you can choose one of the following two patterns

1. Delegate Pattern

Define a protocol in your TabelView2Controller's header file. In that protocol, define a method used for notify selection update in tableView2Controller.

```
//TableView2Controller.h
@protocol TableView2ControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)updateSelectedMenu:(NSString *)selectedMenu;

@interface TableView2Controller: UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedMune;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<tableView2ControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Make your TodoListViewController conforms this protocol.

You should set the TodoListViewController as the delegate of TableView2Controller.If you are using Storyboard, you should do it in TodoListViewController's method `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

Then in TableView2Controller's UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you can call `updateSelectedMenu:` to notify delegate that your choice is changed. And in `updateSelectedMenu:` method of TodoListViewController, you can update your UI according to the input parameter.

2. Notification Pattern

Define a NSNotification in your TableView2Controller. Store the selected menu string in the notification's userInfo, and post this notification in TableView2Controller's UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
//TableView2Controller.h
extern NSString *const TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification;
extern NSString *const TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuKey;

@interface TableView2Controller: UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *selectedMune;
@end

//TableView2Controller.m
NSString *const TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification = @"TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification";
NSString *const TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuKey = @"TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuKey";

@implementation TableView2Controller
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSDictionary *userInfo = @{TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuKey: self.selectedMune};
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
}
@end
```

Register TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification in TodoListViewController

```
// TodoListViewController.m
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(selectedMenuUpdateNotification:) 
                                                 name:TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuDidChangedNotification
                                              object:nil]; 
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Then in `selectedMenuUpdateNotification:` method of TodoListViewController, you can get the update selectedMenu using TableView2ControllerSelectedMenuKey in userInfo and update your UI accordingly.